# Android Database creation & listview

Tags: android

Hi i am very new to android.I want to create database in SQLite for android application.The data from database will be displayed in listview (image, name) using cursor adapter.what is the best way to do this. Should i have to have holder class too to hold views created for custom list. Can some one will guide me in this with example... Step by step explanation is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am working with the Qt and there are examples with SQLite database. I mean this shouldn't be such a big problem because Android has preinstalled SQLite drivers. Maybe look for Java examples on google

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html) complete example of Dynamic ListView